# Is there a way to add rounded corners to a DropdownButton menu item list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add rounded corners to a DropdownButton menu items list. I want to add rounded corners to the actual menu item list, not the DropdownButton.

[UI of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdCxd.png)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the code of the list / items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible to do that with a `DropdownButton`, you could achieve that with a `PopupMenuButton`, like this:

```
int _selected = 1;

Center(
  child: PopupMenuButton(
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      child: Text('Selected item: $_selected'),
    ),
    onSelected: (value) => setState(() => _selected = value),
    color: Colors.greenAccent,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0))),
    itemBuilder: (context) {
      return [1, 2, 3]
          .map((value) => PopupMenuItem(
              value: value,
              child: Container(
                child: Text('$value'),
              )))
          .toList();
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about PopupMenuButton.